# React with Typescript - stopwatch component

Tags: react.js, typescript

I've been trying to learn React and I'm currently building a time-tracking application. The-end goal of the app will be for users to be able to track time against different tasks from different projects.

This is the stopwatch component I have built, with a start, end and reset button, and I would like to get a code review to see if I'm on the right path in terms of clean code and the use of React hooks.

````
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export interface IStopwatchProps {}

export interface IStopwatchState {}

const StartButton = styled.button`
  background: green;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
`;

const StopButton = styled.button`
  background: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
`;

const ResetButton = styled.button`
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
`;

const Stopwatch: React.FunctionComponent<IStopwatchProps> = (
  props
): React.ReactElement => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0);
  const [hours, SetHours] = useState(0);
  const [displaySeconds, setDisplaySeconds] = useState("00");
  const [displayMinutes, setDisplayMinutes] = useState("00");
  const [displayHours, setDisplayHours] = useState("00");
  const [isStopWatchRunning, setStopwatchState] = useState(false);
  const toggleState = () => setStopwatchState(!isStopWatchRunning);
  const resetStopwatch = () => {
    setSeconds(0);
    setMinutes(0);
    SetHours(0);
    setDisplaySeconds("00");
    setDisplayMinutes("00");
    setDisplayHours("00");
    setStopwatchState(false);
  };

  const setDisplayValue = (timeValue: number): string => {
    return timeValue > 9
      ? "" + timeValue.toString()
      : "0" + timeValue.toString();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval: number = 0;
    if (isStopWatchRunning) {
      interval = window.setInterval(() => {
        let displayValueSeconds = setDisplayValue(seconds);
        setDisplaySeconds(displayValueSeconds);
        let displayValueMinutes = setDisplayValue(minutes);
        setDisplayMinutes(displayValueMinutes);
        let displayValueHours = setDisplayValue(hours);
        setDisplayHours(displayValueHours);
        setSeconds(seconds + 1);
        if (seconds === 59) {
          setSeconds(0);
          setMinutes(minutes + 1);
        }
        if (minutes === 59) {
          setMinutes(0);
          SetHours(hours + 1);
        }
      }, 1000);
    } else if (!isStopWatchRunning && seconds !== 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [isStopWatchRunning, seconds, minutes, hours]);
  return (
    <div>
      <StartButton onClick={toggleState}>Start</StartButton>
      <StopButton onClick={toggleState}>End</StopButton>
      <ResetButton onClick={resetStopwatch}>Reset</ResetButton>
      <h1>
        {displayHours} : {displayMinutes} : {displaySeconds}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Stopwatch;
```
````

Comment: Maybe a rule of thumb that can help you: if you have 2 (or more) states that are always changing together, then they can be only one state. For example in the above example, it feels that you need only   2 states (maybe 3 for the `interval`): one to model if the watch is running or not and one for the number of seconds passed. Everything else can be computed during each render from this number of seconds. Doing it like that would probably help simplify the code a lot.